# Getting active sort on columns

Tags: wpf, spreadsheetgear

I'm using spreadsheetgear to push data to a WPF client via TCP/IP socket and DataTable... I need to save before the new data are pushed to the table the existing sorting options in order to restore the after the update.
I've not found any information on documentation/looking at the properties exposed. Is it possible? I've a IRange range and I've almost tried each property..
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpreadsheetGear provides no API to determine what columns might have previously had a sort applied to it.  If your goal is to revert a sheet data to some state before a sort was applied, this really is not possible--even in Excel--unless you have an extra column somewhere in the sorted range with, say, an auto-incrementing number, which you could use to sort ascending as your final step and which would effectively "revert" the sheet data back to its original order.